# Breakdown and interpret the ARIMA model

Tags: forecasting, arima, modeling, interpretation, seasonality

Electricity usage goes up during winter because heating is used
Electricity usage goes up during summer because air conditioner used.

$$y^*_t = \beta_1x^*_{1,t} + \beta_2x^*_{2,t} + \eta_t,$$
$$(1-\Phi_{1}B^{12} - \Phi_{2}B^{24})(1-B)(1-B^{12})\eta_t = (1+\theta_1 B)\varepsilon_t$$
$y^*_t = \log(y_t)$, $x^*_{1,t} = \sqrt{x_{1,t}}$ and $x^*_{2,t}=\sqrt{x_{2,t}}$.

Following is the ARIMA model for it.

ARIMA(0,1,1)(2,1,0)$_{12}$

However, I am not sure how to actually interpret it/How this model is actually derived. Can someone please explain/break it down for me?

Comment: What are your $x$s?

Comment: So there are 2 factors. e.g. cooling and heating temperature. cooling x1 - 18C - the average daily temperature when the daily average is below 18C otherwise its 0. heating x2 + 18C - the average daily temperature when the daily average is above18C otherwise its 0.